# PDF page size with Latex

Tags: pdf

I made a pdf file using Latex but the size is 49% by default.

[image]

How can I change it to 100% by default ?

Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By 49% I assume that's the zoom level of the viewer you're using. You can adjust this as part of the PDF using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)'s `pdfstartview` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfstartview = XYZ null null 1.00,% x y zoom
  pdfstartpage = 1
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Note that this is viewer dependent, and most likely will only result in a start view at 100% if you use Adobe Reader.

Comment: Hello It helped , but when I open it it become the main page is 2 , the front page is not the first anymore.

Comment: @AhMed: See my update to the answer.